# How to replace obsolete WebClient POST+ZIP with HttpClient in .NET 6

Tags: c#, json, dotnet-httpclient, .net-6.0

Since WebClient is deprecated in .NET 6, what is the best solution to convert the following code using WebClient with an equivalent code using HttpClient?

```cs
byte[] data = Converter(...); // object to zipped json string

var client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
client.Headers.Add("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

byte[] response = webClient.UploadData("...url...", "POST", data);
string body = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
```

This code works but only accepts simple json strings as input:

```cs
var request = new HttpRequestMessage()
{
    RequestUri = new Uri("...url..."),
    Version = HttpVersion.Version20,
    Method = HttpMethod.Post,
    Content = new StringContent("...json string...", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
};

var client = new HttpClient();
var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
```

I need a solution to post a zipped json string.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

No surprise you managed to only send simple strings, because you used **String**Content, which is meant for (drum roll!) **string** content.

So, what to do if you want to send binary data in form of a **byte array**? Well, the answer is simple: Don't use *StringContent*. Instead, use (drum roll intensifies) [**ByteArrayContent**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.bytearraycontent).

Comment: I have seen this class, but how do I set the content encoding and content type? with request.Headers.Add(...)?

Answer (score 0):

In order to add content type you could do this:

```
var content = new StringContent(payload, Encoding.UTF8);
content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
```

If you want to add headers like you did with webclient:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

//OR 

var header = new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key: "Accept", value: "application/json");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(header.Key, header.Value));
```